# Angular 6 : Sending authenticated request

Tags: angular, jwt, angular6

i am trying to implement angular2-jwt sending implementation request in angular 6 but i am getting errors that seem this package isn't available for angular 6

My code :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { AuthHttp, AuthConfig } from 'angular2-jwt';

export function authHttpServiceFactory(http: Http, options: RequestOptions) {
  return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
    tokenName: 'token',
        tokenGetter: (() => sessionStorage.getItem('token')),
        globalHeaders: [{'Content-Type':'application/json'}],
    }), http, options);
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: AuthHttp,
      useFactory: authHttpServiceFactory,
      deps: [Http, RequestOptions]
    }
  ]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Error:

```
ERROR in node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.d.ts(3,10): error TS2305: Module '"D:/.../.../.../node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observable'.
```

Comment: check the question now

Comment: Seems to be a version conflict regarding rxjs.

Comment: yes maybe because i am using angular 6 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of `angular-jwt` you are using doesn't support Angular 6 and RxJS 6.

You should remove this version and install the newer one:

`npm install @auth0/angular-jwt`

and use it as follows:

```
import { JwtModule } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

export function tokenGetter() {
  return localStorage.getItem('jwt');
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // this is the specific part
    HttpClientModule,
    JwtModule.forRoot({
      config: { tokenGetter }
    }),
  ]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

This will make every HTTP request made with `HttpClient` inside the `AuthModule` have credentials automatically sent with it.

You can use the utility funcitons provided by the library (checking for token validity, etc.) by injecting `JwtHelperService` inside your components/services:

```
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';

@Injectable
export class MyService {
  constructor(private jwtUtil: JwtHelperService) {}
}
```

You can read the documentation [here](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt).

Comment: ok now how to implement jwthelperservice in place of old version ?

Comment: ok man how can i use authmodule method in this function

  getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http
      .get(this.baseUrl + 'users', this.jwt())
      .pipe(map(res => <User[]>res.json()))
      .pipe(catchError(this.handlerError));
  }

Comment: The `JwtModule` sets up HTTP interceptors which add the required authentication headers to every request so you don't have to do anything on your side. You have to use the `HttpClient` to make requests: `httpClient.get(this.baseUrl + ...)`.

Comment: where can we talk to clarify everything man because it's my first time to use jwt authentication and i don't know that much about it

Comment: getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http
      .get(this.baseUrl + 'users')
      .pipe(map(res => <User[]>res.json()))
      .pipe(catchError(this.handlerError));
  }

i am getting error : 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182498/discussion-between-james-fallon-and-tsvetan-ganev).